# Unified ARM Cortex M3 documentation

Tags: arm

I have discovered to some extend overlapping documentation between
ARM core (from ARM) and vendor specific documentation, which repeats
information of ARM core already given by ARM itself. Given
STM32F10xxx/20xxx/21xxx/L1xxxx as an device family example, there is
quite a lot of redundant core specific information distributed over
6 datasheets and manuals, coming from ARM and STM.

My question is, are there any efforts to make those information less
redundant from ARM core implementing companies ? Thank for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

typically with arm and I assume other IP vendors cores (mips, etc) you want to get the documentation for the core specifically from the ip vendor (arm).  In this case http://infocenter.arm.com get the ARM Architectural Reference Manual (ARM ARM) for the ARMv7-M, and then under Cortex-M get the Cortex-m3 or m4 or m0 Technical Reference Manual (TRM), ideally get the manual specific to the revision of the core in the device, if the chip vendor has provided that information (even if it is not the most recent manual).

From a chip vendors perspective any time you create a programmers reference manual when you have purchased ip inside your part you still want to have a complete manual for the users.  I think ARM restricts how much you can/should publish and prefers to provide core documentation. Peripherals like the timer inside the Cortex-M3 which has an offset driven by ARM but a base address driven by the chip vendor you will often see described in both chip and ip vendor manuals.  Unlike ARM some IP vendors dont want users to see their manuals they want the chip vendor to deal with providing and supporting programming support.  So on an IP vendor by IP vendor basis and on a chip vendor by chip vendor basis you are going to see a large mix of solutions to the documentation problem.

Within a single chip vendor company you will see the same habits, perhaps because there is only one person or team that writes all the manuals for a family of chips or through company policies/practices, or because the next chip manual steals a fair amount of logic and content from the prior chip and chip manual (cut and paste and change a few things as needed).

What you wont see is two competing chip vendors standardizing.  See if you can get Intel and AMD to jointly create an x86 manual or conform to the same standards for chip pinout, footprint, power, etc.  One might copy the other to make a drop in replacement or source code compatible part, but you wont normally see chip vendors get along that well.  It normally is not in their best interest to do so.  They might have to buy each others ip blocks or have lawyers write up patent royalty payment agreements and such things, but you wont see them sit side by side and work on something unless forced for some reason.

The perfect example is the system timer inside the cortex-m3 or information about internal core interrupt information or something like that, esp if the vendor has added their own interrupt logic and registers outside the arm core.  Rarely, unless a successfully licensed clone (xscale) will you see a full instruction set.

If the vendors were to publish that information themselves it would be more chaotic, less standardized. Forcing programmers to go here and there and the other place to find docs that have moved or dont exist because you dont want to or wont publish in your document is a bit off putting to programmers, at the same time though the experience is consistent, arm programmers use ARM docs, and the arm core side of it is a consistent experience across chip vendors.